# Guice custom scope entry and exit in Java console application

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, interceptor

I'm currently trying to implement injection in a Java console application using Guice. The application imports XML files in a database. Every import operation is done in an `AbstractImporter`, which can either be a `UserImporter`, a `ScheduleImporter`, etc.

```
public class ScheduleMigrator extends AbstractMigrator {
    private final UserImporter userImporter;
    private final ScheduleImporterFactory scheduleImporterFactory;

    @Inject
    public ScheduleMigrator(UserImporter userImporter,
                            ScheduleImporterFactory scheduleImporterFactory) {
        this.userImporter = userImporter;
        this.scheduleImporterFactory = scheduleImporterFactory;
    }

    public void migrate() {
        // Migrate users
        userImporter.run();

        // Migrate schedules for each type
        for (ScheduleType scheduleTypes : ScheduleType.values()) {
            ScheduleImporter importer =
                scheduleImporterFactory.create(scheduleTypes);
            importer.run();
        }
    }

}

public class UserImporter extends AbstractImporter {

    private final UserTransformer userTransformer;
    private final ConfigurationService configurationService;

    @Inject
    public UserImporter(UserTransformer userTransformer,
                        ConfigurationService configurationService) {
        this.userTransformer = userTransformer;
        this.configurationService = configurationService;
    }

    public void run() {
        // do stuff here
    }
}

@Singleton
public class UserTransformer {
    // ...code ommited...

}

@ImporterScoped
public class ConfigurationService {
    // ...code ommited...

}
```

I have successfully created my own scope (`@ImporterScoped`) for classes that should only be available and instantiated only in an `Importer`. The scope was created by following the steps in [the wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomScopes). My problem is, how should I enter and exit the scope in `ScheduleMigrator`?

As you can see in `ScheduleMigrator`, each `Importer` is injected and its `run()` method is invoked. There are also factories (based on Guice's `@AssistedInject` feature). This is where I want each scope to start and end, `UserImporter` and `ScheduleImporterFactory` should run in their own scope.

This is a rough idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
importerScope.enter();
(new UserImporter()).run();
importerScope.exit();
```

Guice's documentation mentions the use of interceptors, but I'm a little lost on how it can be implemented.

Comment: What Scope implementation are you using? What code triggers an importer to execute? What is the lifecycle of an importer object? Guide AOP is one potential way to solve this problem but I think it's probably not necessary in this case.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly... I use a custom scope implemented by following the wiki guide on custom scopes. I have updated my original question in order to include information on how `Importer`s get instantiated and run, hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AOP seems a very over-engineered approach and might introduce problems. When do I enter the scope? When do I exit? What happens if I instantiate two `Importer` objects?

Instead, I added a `runScoped` method in `AbstractMigrator` that takes a `Runnable` and executes it. Using injection I get the `ImporterScope` scope, enter and exit it appropriately.

```
protected void runScoped(Runnable function)
{
    scenarioScope.enter();

    try {
        function.run();
    }
    finally {
        scenarioScope.exit();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
runScoped(() -> {
    ScheduleImporter importer =
            scheduleImporterFactory.create(scheduleTypes);
    importer.run();
});
```

This introduces one problem though. In `ScheduleMigrator`, I can't have `Importers` injected, because their instantiation would occur outside of a scope and Guice throws an `OutOfScopeException`. I had to wrap each `Importer` in a `Provider`.

```
private final Provider<UserImporter> userImporterProvider;

runScoped(() -> {
    UserImporter importer = userImporterProvider.get();
    importer.run();
});
```

Comment: Yes, something like this was what I was alluding to in my comment. I would probably use a Guice MapBinder to bind a `Map<ImporterKind, Provider<Importer>>` and inject that into a utility class that could encapsulate the `runScoped()` implementation. Then you would just call `runScoped(ImporterKind)` and it would open the scope, call `get()` on the corresponding provider and `run()` it, and then close the scope. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does make sense! I'm new to Guice (and injection in general) so I'm having a difficult time understanding how `runScoped(ImporterKind)` could work

Comment: I'm imagining that `ImporterKind` would be an enum, with values like `USER`, `SCHEDULE`, etc. -- but I may not have a good grasp of your problem space here.